# Why python struct adds padding when a short would be placed to an odd address? (Python 3.7.2)

Tags: python, struct, padding

The code section below fails with

Exception has occurred: error
unpack requires a buffer of 52 bytes

```
self.masterstructdef = 'HH8sHBBBBHLHHHHBBBBBBBHHLL'
strcut.unpack(self.masterstructdef, buffer)
```

because the size of buffer is 51 and the structure size (after the padding) became 52.

How do I convince python not to add padding bytes?

Comment: Because that's how a C compiler would lay out a C struct.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/struct.html
"Note By default, the result of packing a given C struct includes pad bytes in order to maintain proper alignment for the C types involved; similarly, alignment is taken into account when unpacking. This behavior is chosen so that the bytes of a packed struct correspond exactly to the layout in memory of the corresponding C struct. To handle platform-independent data formats or omit implicit pad bytes, use standard size and alignment instead of native size and alignment: see Byte Order, Size, and Alignment for details."